# In mathematica, how can I execute multiple expressions in do loop?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to realize this function:
Do[
expr(1),
expr(2)...
expr(n),
{i,1,j}]

to execute expr(k), the result of expr(k-1) is required, so the function can not realized by simply multiple layer of do loop. How can I execute the function by do loop? Or by other loop in mathematica?(I also notice that both for and while loop can only support one expr just as do loop)

Comment: You seem to be learning Mathematica.  You might want to direct your questions to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4):

Try separating by semicolon rather than comma.  Like:

```
y = 0
Do[y += x; Print[y], {x, 1, 5}]
```

Comment: Super, @PengPeng - happy to help!  Do please 'accept' the answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Do loops, and many of the other control-flow constructs from imperative programming languages, are almost always **not** the right answer to Mathematica programming questions.

You don't tell us what `expr` is supposed to calculate so it's difficult to provide more than a very general answer ... so I'll use the factorial as a simple example of how one might program a function where `expr[n]` depends on `expr[n-1]`

```
fact[0] = 1
fact[n_] := n*fact[n-1]
```

Here, I've defined the factorial function in two rules; the first establishes the base case, and the second establishes the case for values other than `0`.  To avoid situations where the function is fed bad data we'd probably prefer a formulation such as

```
fact[0] = 1
fact[n_Integer /; n > 0] := n*fact[n-1]
```

In this version the function `fact` will only operate on positive integers or on `0`.

(*Note: to those knowledgeable about Mathematica: Yes I know that this is not a good way to program the factorial function, and that there is a built-in function for calculating factorials.  But this is supposed to help someone who appears to be a complete novice.*)